# scipy.signal.convolve gives different result than manual computation of convolution integral

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

Say I have two functions,

> *f(t) = sin(t)*

and

> *g(t) = cost(t)*

I know that the convolution of *f* and *g* is

> *0.5 * t * sin(t)*

(solved by hand [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform/convolution-integral/v/introduction-to-the-convolution)), and by sympy below:

```
import sympy as sp

t, tau = sp.symbols('t tau')
sol = sp.integrate(sp.sin(t - tau) * sp.cos(tau), (tau, 0, t))
print(sol)
# t*sin(t)/2
```

How would I get to this result with scipy's `convolve`?  Currently I'm getting two very different outputs:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
f = np.sin(t)
g = np.cos(t)
conv = 0.5 * t * np.sin(t)

print(conv)
# [-2.72  -2.63  -2.54  -2.449 -2.357 -2.264 -2.171 -2.078 -1.984 -1.89  ...,
#  -1.89  -1.984 -2.078 -2.171 -2.264 -2.357 -2.449 -2.54  -2.63  -2.72 ]

print(signal.convolve(f, g, mode='same'))
# [ 138.098  134.167  130.164  126.092  121.953  117.747  113.476  109.142
#   104.746  100.29  ...,  -95.775 -100.29  -104.746 -109.142 -113.476
#  -117.747 -121.953 -126.092 -130.164 -134.167]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `signal.convolve` method performs summation. To make it approximate integration, you need to multiply by dt, the step size.

Second, the integral that produces 0.5*t*sin(t) only involves the values starting from 0: you integrate f(tau)*g(t-tau) with tau from 0 to t. To mimic this with discrete convolution, begin the linspace from 0, and choose  mode='full', then truncating the result to size, starting from beginning. This way, the first elements of convolution will involve very few terms, so they begin essentially with 0.

```
n = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
dt = t[1] - t[0]
f = np.sin(t)
g = np.cos(t)
conv = 0.5 * t * np.sin(t)
conv2 = signal.convolve(f, g, mode='full')[:n] * dt
plt.plot(t, conv)   # assuming import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
plt.plot(t, conv2)
plt.show()
```

[image: compare]

To get the negative part, so the same thing but with `t = -np.linspace(0, 10, n)`. Note that t should go backwards now, still starting from 0 - as the integral does.